# Running file as scheduled task is not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, windows, scheduled-tasks, csvde

I've written a script in c# which I have to execute on a daily basis. It's something like an updater for my data base. So it pulls some data from the Active Directory using CSVDE, and saves that info into csv files in the same directory, then parses those files and updates my database if necessary. Obviously I don't want to run it manually every day, so instead I added a scheduled task. My problem is that it doesn't create the expected files, at least in the same path. If I run the script manually it works like a charm. Also after a scheduled run I tried to find those files by filename on the machine to check whether those were created in some other place, but no luck.
Do you have any idea why it not works the same way?

Comment: probably ServerFault.com - but did you set proper working directory in scheduled task properties?

Comment: What account is the Task Scheduler running it under? Did you check the permissions etc. ?

Comment: It's running using a dedicated local admin account. Permissions are OK. Working directory has been set as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some issue with the credentials under the script ran. Solved now.